# Insert data into table where if the values does not exist for particular columns it should enter zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I am pretty new to mysql. I have set of csv files which I want to insert into different tables. I have fixed 100 columns for all the files. But, some files contain values only upto 50 column. So I want to insert zero value for all the other columns. Can someone please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

set default value as 0 for other columns

Answer (score 0):

One can use mysql native function: `LOAD DATA INTO` this comes with variety options, explore the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)